# Options in buildEdge shinyCyJS

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I'm making a graph in Shiny using shinyCyJS, I'm building the edges with buildElems that calls buildEdge:

```
edges = data.frame(
    source = c("v1","v2","v3","v4","v4"),
    target = c("v2","v3","v4","v2","v1"),targetArrowShape ='triangle',targetArrowColor = "#000000"
  )
edges = buildElems(edges, type = 'Edge')
```

But the parameters aren't working, I want to:

- Build a simple arrow from source to target.
- Make the edge black.
- Write a legend above the edge.

How can I do those? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
edges = data.frame(
    source = c("v1","v1","v2","v3","v3"),
    target = c("v2","v3","v4","v2","v4"),
    label = c("7","3","2","2","8"),
    lineColor = "#9b9b9b",
    curveStyle='bezier',
    targetArrowColor = 'black',
    sourceArrowColor = 'black',
    targetArrowShape ='triangle',
    sourceArrowShape = 'none'
  )
```